# android how not to mark certain view in the row, but not the row itself in listview

Tags: android, listview, layout, android-listview, android-linearlayout

i have a **listview** in which each row contains a **checkbox** and a **horizontal linearLayout** right to the checkbox. the linear layout's background is a drawable, and the layout itself contains two **textViews** side by side (big text and small text -sometimes it is hidden tho):

[image: this is how each row looks like:]

What i want that when someone clicks on a row, the checkbox will flip its status, and it does.
I never want the row itself to change color, however, what happens now is that when i click on the LinearLayout (that contains the textViews), the row itself and the linear layout changes the color to orange,

[image: when i click a row]

but i want only the linearLayout with the textViews to change its color.
I managed to do it with TextView with drwable background but here it has to be LinearLayout becuase it has to contain two textViews.

so my question is, how do i make this heppen, meaning that when someone clicks on the linearLayout, then the LinearLayout will change its color to orange, without the line to change its color??
Thanks!

**here is my row.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout 
    android:id="@+id/LinearLayout11" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:gravity="center_vertical" 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
    android:layout_width="match_parent">
    <CheckBox 
        android:paddingLeft="6dp" 
        android:button="@drawable/custom_checkbox" 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:checked="true" 
        android:focusable="false" 
        android:id="@+id/interest_checkbox">
    </CheckBox>
    <LinearLayout 
        android:gravity="center_vertical" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:id="@+id/LinearLayout12" 
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" 
        android:paddingLeft="6dp" 
        android:weightSum="1" 
        android:paddingRight="6dp" 
        android:layout_marginRight="6dp" 
        android:background="@drawable/row_state">
        <TextView 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
            android:textColor="@android:color/black" 
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" 
            android:layout_width="0dp" 
            android:layout_weight="1" 
            android:id="@+id/interest_summary" android:text="Big Text">
        </TextView>
        <TextView 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
            android:textColor="@color/back" 
            android:gravity="left" 
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" 
            android:layout_width="0dp" 
            android:id="@+id/TextView11" 
            android:layout_weight="1" 
            android:text="small text">
        </TextView>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

**and here is row_state.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    >
    <item 
        android:state_pressed="true"
        android:drawable="@drawable/row_clicked" 
        /> <!-- pressed -->    
    <item 
        android:state_focused="true"
        android:drawable="@android:drawable/editbox_background_normal" 
        /> <!-- focused -->    
    <item 
        android:drawable="@drawable/row" 
        /> <!-- default -->
</selector>
```

Comment: Show your getView (or simplified version of it minus any proprietary code you want to hide).

Edit: If you're using the list selector to alter the background color then that is your issue. List selectors -will- affect the whole row, you'll need to individually (in getView) set the color based on the check boxes state.

Comment: i dont want the linearLayout to stay with this color. it's just for the moment of the click, regardless of the checkbox's state

Answer (score 0):

You need to override bindView of your SimpleCursorAdapter:

```
SimpleCursorAdapter myAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(...) {
    public void bindView(View view, android.content.Context context, Cursor cursor) {
        final LinearLayout layout = view.findViewById(R.id.somelinearlayout);

        // Add an onclick handler to the LinearLayout
        layout.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            // Add click handler that alters the background
        }); 
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks Austin, but i'm afraid i didn't explain myself propely.
i **dont** want the color to change according to the state of the checkbox. **My question is about the moment of the click**. for send after i click the row changes its color.

Comment: See my editing - add an onClick or onFocus listener to the linear layout and alter the background accordingly - ie. when in focus you set the background one way and revert it when losing focus.

Answer (score 0):

set Background of CheckBox too with similar state list.. just like row_state.xml and probably u can do this..

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    >
    <item 
        android:state_pressed="true"
        android:drawable="@drawable//*default checkBox color*/" 
        /> <!-- pressed -->    
    <item 
        android:state_focused="false"
         android:drawable="@drawable//*default checkBox color*/" 
        /> <!-- focused -->    
    <item 
         android:drawable="@drawable//*default checkBox color*/" 
        /> <!-- default -->
</selector>
```